# Write with Powershell into a Excel file

Tags: excel, powershell

I would like to fill my Excel file with powershell. The code works as long as I use only numbers. As soon as I use a variable of a word the code does not work anymore and the following error occurs. "**Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Int32**'." I tried to catch the error by intercepting the value and if it is text converting it to a string. Unfortunately it still does not work. Thanks for your help :)

```
$excelFilePath = "C:\Users\Test\test.xlsx"

$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($excelFilePath)
$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

$Column = $Worksheet.Columns.Item(2)
$Column.Interior.ColorIndex = 6

$columnCount = 5
$rowCount = 13
$four = "four"


$values = @(
    @(1, 'two', 3, $four, 5),
    @(6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
    @(11, 12, 13, 14, 15),
    @(16, 17, 18, 19, 20),
    @(21, 22, 23, 24, 25),
    @(26, 27, 28, 29, 30),
    @(31, 32, 33, 34, 35),
    @(36, 37, 38, 39, 40),
    @(41, 42, 43, 44, 45),
    @(46, 47, 48, 49, 50),
    @(51, 52, 53, 54, 55),
    @(56, 57, 58, 59, 60),
    @(61, 62, 63, 64, 65)
)

# insert data into table
for ($row = 1; $row -le $rowCount; $row++) {
    for ($col = 1; $col -le $columnCount; $col++) {
        $value = $values[$row - 1][$col - 1]
        $cell = $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, $col)

        if ($value.GetType().Name -eq "Int32") {
            $cell.Value2 = $value
        }
        else {
            $cell.Value2 = [System.Convert]::ToString($value)
        }
    }
}


$Column = $Worksheet.Columns.Item(2) 
$Column.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 

$Workbook.Save()
$Workbook.Close()
$Excel.Quit()
```

I tried it with numbers only and it worked. There I tried this code in the "#insert data into table"

```
#insert data into table
for ($row = 1; $row -le $rowCount; $row++) {
    for ($col = 1; $col -le $columnCount; $col++) {
        $value = $values[$row - 1][$col - 1]
        $cell = $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, $col)
        $cell.Value2 = $value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :)

```
# insert data into table
for ($row = 1; $row -le $rowCount; $row++) {
    for ($col = 1; $col -le $columnCount; $col++) {
        $value = $values[$row - 1][$col - 1]

        # Prüfen, ob $value eine Zahl oder ein String ist
        if ($value -is [int] -or $value -is [double]) {
            $cell = $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, $col)
            $cell.Value2 = $value
        }
        else {
            $cell = $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, $col)
            $cell.Value2 = "$value" 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, your answer can be improved by providing additional supporting information, such as how it's correct with citations or documentation.